# How to place picture on desktop, on top of wallpaper?

Tags: linux, gnome-3

How to place picture on desktop, on top of wallpaper?

This is for Fedora 26, Gnome 3.24.2

Comment: This is a programming Q&A site, not a software help site. Flagging to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: This is programming site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about pictures but maybe you can use [conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky)

Comment: Ah, just beat me to it.

Comment: conky does not work with Wayland, but monkey does.  https://github.com/monky-hs/monky

Answer (score 1):

Conky can be used to do this. See here: [how to install](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/07/conky-collection-for-ubuntulinux.html).

Although this software has a lot more options to add additions to your desktop, it will do the trick for images too.

Windows equivalent is [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/).

1 minute too short to answering. See above.